# How is the temporal coherence of a pulse defined?

Tags: quantum-optics, coherence

I am having problem with the concept of coherence and photon degeneracy.

The temporal coherence of pulse is defined in Born and Wolf as:
$$t_c=\lambda^2/c\Delta\lambda$$

(The time a photon takes to travel a pulse length)

A pulse is considered temporally coherent if the pulse duration is comparable or smaller than the coherence time.

So if we chirp (add group delay dispersion GGD) a single cycle laser pulse so its pulse duration become 100 times longer ( let say travel through glass so its pulse duration broadens while preserving the spectral compnents) would that make the pulse "temporally incoherent" or reduce the number of coherent photons ?

Spectral components with close frequency will still be close together.